# Installing mint instead of ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, formatting

I've ubuntu on my laptop, I'd like to remove it and install mint instead. What is the safest way to do it?
ubuntu formatting

Answer (score 2):

If it is the only OS currently on your system, simply install in the same fashion as you installed Ubuntu. Burn it to a disk, boot from it and follow the instructions. Once prompted for the disk partitioning scheme, you'll want to use the **entire disk** and wipe out the Ubuntu install.

If you currently have other OSs, the Mint installer is pretty good at picking those up and will allow you to utilize GRUB to dual boot with Windows for example.

Comment: BACK UP FIRST!  Following John's instructions would result in wiping out all your data!  Back up and *check the backup* before you format your hard disk.

Comment: @CarlF... that is what he wants.

Comment: John T, he didn't say "I want to delete all my documents and other personal files."

Answer (score 2):

Just overwrite it. I've never installed Mint, but just tell him to use the root-partition of Ubuntu (format it of course), and your Home-Partition (if any, but don't format it ;) ).

Comment: Most people don't actually have separate partitions, Bobby.  Yeah, the instructions often say to do that, but people don't.

Comment: @CarlF: I know, that's why I wrote "if any". ;) Having a separate Home-Partition is one of the greatest things about Linux, but everyone has to learn this by his own, I guess.